# Is there a way to make a triangular, clickable box in html/css?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Ok, so I want to develop a web portal page that can direct you to multiple websites that I have. I want to design it like this: [image] 
Where each section is a clickable section with JS and when hovered it pops up a bit and fades into a picture of some sort. Anyways, my question is how would I get a div to be angled like this? I read about using the border trick to make a CSS triangle, but I don't believe that will work for this. I was also thinking if there were a way to use the CSS transform property somehow but I cannot like up the triangles uniformly around the page and then keep it scalable so it's responsive. Does anyone have any suggestions? Or is this even possible??

Comment: You could always go old school and use an [image map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map)

Comment: I was actually thinking of going this way but it just seems trivial and too outdated of a method :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS offers something called clip-masks. This allows you to move past basic color shapes and allows for the shaping of images. This would look good when used as the links you want.

See more about clip-paths: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip-path/

A useful site for deriving the actual CSS for the shape can be found here: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

This used in conjunction with media queries for responsiveness and absolute positioning for arrangement should get you where you want to be.

Comment: This is promising, however, I cannot get multiple clip-paths on the same page. I can get one section of the image to display and be clickable, but I want all four sections (the entire image) to be displayed but to be clickable. See my above illustration, please.

Comment: NVM, just figured it out...I feel stupid but I just added 4 separate images in, each with a clip-path for each angle, and then I changed the position to absolute for them all to fit together with one another. Thank you so much @Lewis Lockhart for the help!! :)

Comment: Awesome - glad it helped.

Comment: So I have run into another issue. The method you provided me with is working great up to the fact that the clip-path: Shapes() attribute is not compatible with explorer or edge. Edge only supports clip-paths from the URL() source. I've researched SVG heavily to figure out how to implement an SVG path into the html clip-path but I cannot for the life of me figure it out or get anything to work....Do you possibly have any idea of how to go about this?

Comment: Here is what I have so far btw: http://pastiebin.com/embed/5ec610ea799e8 @Lewis

Comment: I would expect any version of Edge 79 or higher to support it (I have not tested it personally). As far as IE goes ... we just need to close the lid on that casket. I'm sorry.

Comment: ok - I just installed the new version of Edge, just for you, and I can confirm that the effect is working. It looks awesome by the way. Great work.

Comment: It does not work with edge unless using defining the clip-path with the url() method. However I cannot get the url() method to work with SVG or anything and was wondering if you knew how or how you got this working? Looking at the compatibility of Clip-Path on MDN's website it shows *Edge only supports clip paths defined by url().

Answer (score -1):

I found this site, maybe it will help:

[CSS Triangle Generator](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/)

I think you can align different triangles with `position: absolute` too.

Comment: No, this does not work as you cannot position them properly the way I want to as well as borders cannot be clickable objects, that I know of.